# How can I find the IP address of my router?

Tags: networking, ip, router

I have read 4-5 articles about it they all tell almost same steps to reset a  password of my router. They tend to start with an instruction along the following lines at which I'm stuck already:

> Open a browser and enter the IP-Address mentioned on the back of the router. save the new password.

Now when I enter `192.168.0.1` in my browser It says the site can not be reached.
I also tried it with `http://192.168.0.1` but no luck it says the same thing

**Question:** Does anyone know what is the problem? Why can't I change the password of my WiFi? Is this an Ubuntu-specific problem but *I don't think so* I think it is browser-specific or IP-specific problem The problem is either with the IP address or the browser, more chances of an IP-specific problem.

I am using Google Chrome browser on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Deepesh, as you know, this site is specifically for Ubuntu-related questions. A good site for your question would be https://superuser.com/. For an overview of the Stackexchange sites, see https://stackexchange.com/sites# , which prominently shows SuperUser as the second-biggest one.

Comment: Of course, I know this site is for Ubuntu specific problems thanks for suggesting superuser.com you should vote to migrate it to that site and I request other to do so instead of downvoting or closing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be that your router is set to a different IP address, Assuming you are connected to the router you can find the IP by opening a terminal and typing the below command and looking for the **Gateway** that relates to the destination `0.0.0.0`

```
route -n
```

Example

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet
```

You can see in this example my routers IP address is `192.168.1.1`

Comment: Ok that worked I was looking for the same That how   can I know the changed IP of my router meanwhile you answered it thanks

Answer (score 3):

I addition to the answer of [@stedotmartin](https://askubuntu.com/a/1072364/51957), you can get the address fully automated with the following expression:

```
route -n | grep "^0.0.0.0" | cut -d ' ' -f 10
```

This only outputs **the internal** address of your router, like

```
192.168.1.1
```

in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Many routers follow the default IP address. Try following:

192.168.1.0 
192.168.0.1

If you still cannot get into your router and you have working internet connection you can copy your public/external IP address from http://whatismyip.live and paste in your browser this will open your router settings directly. So visiting your own public IP address is also your router address. This method works fine for me on TP-link router.

Answer (score 0):

To find IP address of your router and more , I would recommend you a nice gui application called **Nutty**.
It comes default for elementary os. But you can install it for ubuntu using ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bablu-boy/nutty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nutty
```

Then open nutty. Go to **My info** tab. Select network interface. And it will list the details. Also you can see what devices are connected on your network by going to **Devices** tab.
[image: Nutty showing connected devices]

Also you can check your usage and speed and open and closed ports.